# Python and WMI Win_32 classes

Tags: python, automation, system, wmi, infrastructure-as-code

How can I iterate through system summary and components of WMI.

I wan't to print something like hardware resources, components, software environment.
I also wan't to be able to show the components like Multimedia, CD-ROM, Sound Device, Display...

I want to use WMI and WIN32_classes.

So far I have this code but it's not iterating.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

# List with Win32 components:

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-provider

computer_systems = c.Win32_Computersystem()
componenten = c.WIN32_SystemDevices()
drivers = c.Win32_SystemDriver()
printJobs = c.Win32_PrintJob()
netwerkConnecties = c.Win32_NetworkAdapter()
runningTasks = c.Win32_Process()
services = c.Win32_Service()
startupPrograms = c.Win32_StartupCommand()


# print("System Summary: \n\n")
# for computer_system in computer_systems:
#    print(computer_system.Name)

# print("Components: \n")
# for component in componenten:
#    print(component.Name)

print("Software Environment:\n\n")
print("Systeem Drivers: \n ")
for driver in drivers:
    print(driver.Name)

print("\nPrintJob: \n")
for printJob in printJobs:
    print(printJob.Name)

print("\nNetwerk connecties: \n")
for netwerkConnectie in netwerkConnecties:
    print(netwerkConnectie.Name)
    
print("\nRunning Tasks: \n")
for runningTask in runningTasks:
    print(runningTask.Name)

print("\nServices: \n")
for service in services:
    print(service.Name)

print("\nStartup Programs: \n")
for startupProgram in startupPrograms:
    print(startupProgram.Name)
```

Information about WIN32_ (and/or CIM_ classes.) system summary and components overview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the properties of return object/properties of wmi classes

in this case `conn.Win32_Computersystem()` returns a single item containing an object (dict) which has many [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem), one way of accessing desired properties:

```
import wmi

conn = wmi.WMI()

def comp_info():
    cs = conn.Win32_Computersystem()[0]  # accessing first element
    return [
            cs.ChassisSKUNumber,
            cs.Domain,
            cs.Manufacturer,
            cs.Model,
            cs.Name,
            cs.OEMStringArray,
            cs.PartOfDomain,
            cs.PrimaryOwnerName,
            cs.SystemFamily,
            cs.SystemSKUNumber,
            cs.SystemType,
            cs.TotalPhysicalMemory,
            cs.UserName,
            cs.Workgroup
            ]

# looping and printing through returned list   
for i in (comp_info()):
    print(i)
```

similarly you can access the other properties from various wmi classes